# Vue Js API call with dynamic parameters

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js

I'm having issues when trying to create a **dynamic URL** in **Vuejs**. I have the following code.

```
<template>

<input type="text" v-model="searchedLocation" placeholder="Type a place to start"/>

<div class="weather-forecast" v-if="weather"> 
  {{weather}}
  <Card :weather="weather" />
</div>
</template>

<script>
// import Card from './components/Card'
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  created() {
    axios.get(
    `https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=${this.API_KEY}&q=${this.searchedLocation}&aqi=yes`)
    .then(a => this.weather = a.data)
    .catch(err => console.error('Cannot load data', err))
  },

  methods: {
    getCurrentLocation() {
      if(navigator.geolocation) {
        return navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.coordinatesSuccess)
      }
    },
    coordinatesSuccess(position) {
      let coords = position.coords;
      return coords.latitude + ',' + coords.longitude;
    }
  },

  data() {
    return {
      weather: null,
      searchedLocation: this.getCurrentLocation(),
      API_KEY: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    }
  },
  components: {
    Card
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.weather-forecast {
  list-style: none;
}
</style>
```

As shown here, I'm using **HTML5 geolocation** API to get the latitude and longitude.
Then I send these coordinates to **weatherapi** to get a weather report for that coordinates

The thing is that the URL is created like this

```
GET https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=xxxxxxxxxx&q=undefined&aqi=yes
```

The **API_KEY** property has the correct value, but the **q** parameter is **undefined**.

I've been searching a bit and I found that maybe I need to use **computed properties**, but I'm not sure if I need to declare this url as a computed property or just the property **searchedLocation**

I'm using vue 3 + HTML5 geolocation

Comment: In `data() {...` add `console.log(this.getCurrentLocation());` before return. I suppose it's undefined because `getCurrentLocation` is conditional.

Comment: You are trying to fire off an axios get request before your location is defined. A better solution might be to put your `getCurrentLocation()` function in the created hook and chain your axios function to that, so it executes afterward. Also, `coordinatesSuccess` requires a `position` param and when you 'call' this function you (a) never call it - `this.coordinatesSuccess` instead of `this.coordinatesSuccess()` - & there's no way to pass in the position parameter that this function requires. It's also unclear how the `position` parameter is obtained.

Answer (score 0):

Use a method such as `actOnSubmit` below and change your input into a form with a submit button.
If you want to show the weather for the current location by default, initial the
`searchedLocation` inside `created` (also shown in suggestion below).

```
<template>

    <form @submit.prevent="actOnSubmit">
      <input type="text" v-model="searchedLocation" placeholder="Type a place to start"/>
    </form>
    <button type="submit" @click="actOnSubmit">Submit</button>

<div class="weather-forecast" v-if="weather">
  {{weather}}
  <Card :weather="weather" />
</div>
</template>

<script>
// import Card from './components/Card'
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  created() {
    this.searchedLocation = this.getCurrentLocation();
    axios.get(
    `https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=${this.API_KEY}&q=${this.searchedLocation}&aqi=yes`)
    .then(a => this.weather = a.data)
    .catch(err => console.error('Cannot load data', err))
  },

  methods: {
      actOnSubmit() {
        axios.get(
        `https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=${this.API_KEY}&q=${this.searchedLocation}&aqi=yes`)
        .then(a => this.weather = a.data)
        .catch(err => console.error('Cannot load data', err))
      },
      getCurrentLocation() {
          if(navigator.geolocation) {
            return navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.coordinatesSuccess)
          } else {
            return undefined
          }
        },
    coordinatesSuccess(position) {
      let coords = position.coords;
      return coords.latitude + ',' + coords.longitude;
    }
    },

// rest is ok
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to make it work (*not sure if this is the right way but it works*), I share my solution here, maybe someone else finds it useful. Basically I wrapped the **navigator geolocator** inside a promise (*I guess this is an asynchronous operation, it is not deterministic, it can take more or less time*)

Here's my code

```
<template>
<input type="text" v-model="searchedLocation" placeholder="Search"/>

<div class="weather-forecast" v-if="weather"> 
  {{weather}}
  <Card :weather="weather" />
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Card from './components/Card'
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  
  data() {
    return {
      weather: null,
      searchedLocation: this.getCurrentLocation().then(this.getCoordinates),
      API_KEY: 'xxxxxxxxx'
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    axios.get(
      `https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=${this.API_KEY}&q=${this.searchedLocation}&aqi=yes`)
      .then(a => this.weather = a.data)
      .catch(err => console.error('Cannot load data', err))
  },
  
  methods: {
    getCurrentLocation() {
      if(navigator.geolocation) {
        return new Promise((res, rej) => {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(res, rej);
        });
      }
    },

    getCoordinates(a) {
     this.searchedLocation = a.coords.latitude + "," + a.coords.longitude
    }
  },

  components: {
     Card
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.weather-forecast {
  list-style: none;
}
</style>
```

As shown here, I called the method `getCurrentLocation`, this method returns a promise. After return I send a callback to **then** to resolve and get the data and `searchedLocation` received the proper coordinates.